# Process behind gateway ports

Tags: mongodb, docker, networking, gateway

I deployed a mongodb in the default docker network bridge.
Please recall that, the gateway of the bridge network is 172.17.0.1.
For more information, refer to https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/.

Recently, I discovered that the mongodb receives a lot of slow queries from a process running behind 172.17.0.1:39694

How do I find out what process is running on the gateway port 172.17.0.1:39694?

`docker network inspect bridge`
shows only nodes within the bridge network, but shows nothing related what processes are running on its gateway ports.

Comment: Both ends of a TCP connection have a port, and Docker provides a NAT interface for the `docker0` interface.  The only thing that datum tells you on its own is that it's some connection originating from outside Docker; it doesn't point at a specific process and you won't see a server process on that port.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. How do I find out the process outside Docker?
Do you have some specific commands in mind? I inspected `netstat` and `lsof` on the Docker host, but they show nothing useful.

Comment: In the meanwhile, I found a workaround. I just went through all docker containers and checked what was in them. Finally, I found the responsible container. However, this approach is not really feasible, if you have a lot of containers deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Each MongoDB client identifies itself when it establishes the connection. Example:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-25T10:49:02.505-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn216","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:58122","client":"conn216","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-ruby-driver","version":"2.14.0.rc1"},"os":{"type":"linux","name":"linux-gnu","architecture":"x86_64"},"platform":"Ruby 2.7.1, x86_64-linux, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"}}}
```

This gives you the language, driver and driver's version.

You can pass additional metadata to identify connections. For example in Ruby you would do this via [Client#initialize](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/api/Mongo/Client.html#initialize-instance_method) `:app_name` option.

For mapping ports to processes, see e.g. https://www.putorius.net/process-listening-on-port.html

Comment: I'm aware of this possibility, but I really need to identify the actual process/container who causes these slow queries. In this case, I could look into that and adjust or delete it.